# Oracle 11g exception on Fedora 14

Tags: oracle

Hi. I am new to Oracle database. I have installed Oracle using [this](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2010/12/installing-oracle-11g-release-2-on-fedora-14.html) tutorial on my Fedora operating system. It worked fine after installation, and I have made some sample queries and made a new database. Everything was working perfectly.

But after restarting my PC I am not able to start my oracle server using the command `emctl start dbconsole`. It shows the following exception in logs :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:77)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:111)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:174)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:230)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:501)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:436)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:621)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:34)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:492)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:386)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:276)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:212)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:140)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.makeCacheConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:1752)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.makeOneConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:644)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.getCacheConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:592)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.getConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:460)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:544)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:480)
at oracle.sysman.util.jdbc.ConnectionCache._getConnection(ConnectionCache.java:336)
at oracle.sysman.util.jdbc.ConnectionCache._getConnection(ConnectionCache.java:322)
at oracle.sysman.util.jdbc.ConnectionCache.getUnwrappedConnection(ConnectionCache.java:575)
at oracle.sysman.emSDK.svc.conn.FGAConnectionCache.getFGAConnection(FGAConnectionCache.java:207)
at oracle.sysman.emSDK.svc.conn.ConnectionService.getSystemConnection(ConnectionService.java:1383)
at oracle.sysman.emdrep.notification.NotificationMgr.unregisterOMS(NotificationMgr.java:1429)
at oracle.sysman.emdrep.notification.NotificationMgr.destroy(NotificationMgr.java:1878)
at oracle.sysman.emSDK.svc.EMServiceUtil.cleanupServices(EMServiceUtil.java:145)
at oracle.sysman.emSDK.svc.ServiceUtil.cleanupServices(ServiceUtil.java:217)
at oracle.sysman.eml.app.ContextInitializer.contextDestroyed(ContextInitializer.java:819)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.destroyContextListeners(HttpApplication.java:5895)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.destroy(HttpApplication.java:5861)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpSite.destroy(HttpSite.java:875)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpServer.destroy(HttpServer.java:548)
at com.evermind.server.ApplicationServer.destroy(ApplicationServer.java:2074)
at com.evermind.server.ApplicationServerShutdownHandler.run(ApplicationServerShutdownHandler.java:93)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)

2013-04-01 17:27:47,786 [shutdownThread] WARN  jdbc.ConnectionCache _getConnection.353 -     Got a fatal exeption when getting a connection; Error code = 17002; Cleaning up cache and retrying
2013-04-01 17:27:47,787 [shutdownThread] ERROR em.notification unregisterOMS.1438 - Error unregistering: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:77)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:111)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:174)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:230)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:501)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:436)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:621)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:34)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:492)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:386)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:276)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:212)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:140)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.makeCacheConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:1752)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.makeOneConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:644)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.getCacheConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:592)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.getConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:460)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:544)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:248)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:201)
at oracle.sysman.util.jdbc.ConnectionCache._getConnection(ConnectionCache.java:359)
at oracle.sysman.util.jdbc.ConnectionCache._getConnection(ConnectionCache.java:322)
at oracle.sysman.util.jdbc.ConnectionCache.getUnwrappedConnection(ConnectionCache.java:575)
at oracle.sysman.emSDK.svc.conn.FGAConnectionCache.getFGAConnection(FGAConnectionCache.java:207)
at oracle.sysman.emSDK.svc.conn.ConnectionService.getSystemConnection(ConnectionService.java:1383)
at oracle.sysman.emdrep.notification.NotificationMgr.unregisterOMS(NotificationMgr.java:1429)
at oracle.sysman.emdrep.notification.NotificationMgr.destroy(NotificationMgr.java:1878)
at oracle.sysman.emSDK.svc.EMServiceUtil.cleanupServices(EMServiceUtil.java:145)
at oracle.sysman.emSDK.svc.ServiceUtil.cleanupServices(ServiceUtil.java:217)
at oracle.sysman.eml.app.ContextInitializer.contextDestroyed(ContextInitializer.java:819)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.destroyContextListeners(HttpApplication.java:5895)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.destroy(HttpApplication.java:5861)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpSite.destroy(HttpSite.java:875)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpServer.destroy(HttpServer.java:548)
at com.evermind.server.ApplicationServer.destroy(ApplicationServer.java:2074)
at com.evermind.server.ApplicationServerShutdownHandler.run(ApplicationServerShutdownHandler.java:93)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Can someone help me understand why it is showing this error?

Comment: you need to start the database *instance* first. `emctl` starts the "entprise manager", not the database.

Comment: Still, it's symptomatic of overly complex software that something as simple as instance not (yet) running yields so many lines of cr*p.

Answer (score 2):

(a)  Check the status of the listener

```
lsnrctl status
```

It should list the sid of your instance. If not check the tnsnames.ora in ORACLE_HOME/network/admin folder. You can start the listener by using the following statement

```
lsnrctl start
```

(b) Check for the same hostname in /etc/hosts file and the hostname in tnsnames.ora

```
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = strm2.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
```

(c) Check the connection to database with sqlplus using tnsnames i.e

```
sqlplus username/password@"tnsname"
```

(d) Make sure your hosts file contains loopback address.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
```

Comment: thanks Brahman for your detailed response. It is very helpful but my problem was resolved by another effort. I needed to `disable` my selinux. If selinux is `enforcing`, then it don't work. Can you please tell me why is happening? Why do we need to `disable` selinux?

Comment: SELinux feature does not allow the libnnz10.so Oracle library to be loaded and also refer http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100629072125AA7R1HD